# Why do we use symbols as parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, symbols

Model:

```
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :location, dependent: :destroy
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :tweet
end
```

Controller:

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController 
 def index
  @tweets = Tweet.recent.includes(:location) 
 end
end
```

Why do we use symbols (`:location`) as parameters in ruby?

Why does this not work?

```
@tweets = Tweet.recent.includes(location)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common to use hashes passed as arguments to methods because then you don't have to worry about the ordering of arguments. Also, used quite frequently for optional arguments. Consider the examples below:

```
def method_with_args(name, age, dollar_amount, occupation) # gets sort of ugly and error prone
  # do something with args
end

def method_with_hash(hash = {}) # cleans up ordering and forces you to 'name' variables  
  name = hash[:name]
  age = hash[:age]
  dollar_amount = hash[:dollar_amount]
  occupation = hash[:occupation]
  # do stuff with variables
end
```

The second part of your question:

```
@tweets = Tweet.recent.includes(location)
```

location here is expected to be defined as a variable or method on the object that calls the method. If you run the code, the error will prompt you with that information.

In terms of hash access and performance: symbol access to a hash is about 2x faster. String access allocates a string to memory every time it's instantiated which creates a lot of garbage objects. Take a gander at this [blog post](http://www.sitepoint.com/unraveling-string-key-performance-ruby-2-2/)

Comment: Yes, but as the linked text explains, the performance advantage of symbols over strings is much less if the string is frozen. As well, memory requirements do not differ significantly if the string is frozen.

Comment: Ok. :location is a symbol, which represents a string. That string value is our argument. But I have never defined the symbol :location. Why does ruby knows which string is represented by the symbol?

Comment: So ruby doesn't actually know or care what `:location` is. `includes` is an Active Record method that loads relationships during a SQL query into memory. The includes method in ActiveRecord checks the arguments  passed for relationships defined on the class. See: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

Comment: If your question is about how ActiveRecord includes works, you should create a different question on SO

Comment: Ok, no we are getting deeper to my problem. 
I don't understand why "has_one :location and belongs_to :tweet" is enough that Ruby knows how they are connected. I mean the Symbol ":tweet" is in lowercase and the Class in uppercase.

Comment: yep, so your questions are around how Active Record works and how relationships are defined and retrieved. If so, you should start a different SO question. If I've answered your questions regarding this specific issue, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because what you are passing is essentually a string which active record will use to build a sql query. Location without the colon would be a local variable. We could possibly pass a class (Location) but a symbol is more efficient for ActiveRecord purposes. A symbol is a string which is immutable, essentialy a sort of pointer to a string so it is very efficient.